# Framerate Drops way down in Battlefield 3

Tags: windows, graphics, amd-graphics-card

When playing Battlefield 3, I get a framerate of about 20-30 FPS. When playing mutliplayer, maybe after 5 minutes or so the framerate will drop and stay at 4-8 FPS. When a new map is reloaded this resets.

I am wondering if there is any common graphics settings for this. I noticed that Catalyst reports my video memory as 4 GB "Hypermemory". Perhaps at some point RAM is being used for video memory? (The card is 1 GB), maybe disabling this will help?

**Update:**
Using GPU-Z, I noticed that when this happens by GPU load % drops from a steady 100% to 0-10%. So it is as if the graphics card stops being used. The dedicated and shared memory are not going to the capacity of the card, so I don't think hypermemory theory is right.

Comment: Seems to happen after the process memory gets to 1024 as wel... can't find a way to disable Hypermemory. Some things mention a Memory entry in the registry under ATI, but I don't have that. Also "ATI Tool Tray" fails to do it.

Comment: You'll need to post your specs. The number of causes for a dropping framerate are numerous.

Comment: 8 GB RAM i5 M540 2.5 GHz, Raedon Mobility 4670. The card is kind of under powered for the game, but played the entire campaign fine.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming updated drivers, the next common cause of this is overheating. I'm not sure about the 4600 series but the 4800s were notorious for throttling or even crashing due to **memory overheating** not GPU.

Since you got GPUZ, I'd look at the memory temperatures next.

Comment: @surasb: Thanks, do you know what temp in Celsius might cause it to throttle?

Comment: (A quick look at the log from playing earlier show it going up to 90C)

Comment: @KyleBrandt I generally consider my devices to be overheating when they reach within 10% of being able to boil water.

Comment: How else will I heat my tea? I played for a while and didn't have this happen again, but next time I play I will see if it correlates to heat. I bet this is the answer. Ordered a new card for my Desktop that I should get Tuesday anyways :-P

Comment: FYI, I have Xfire 4870s and I have three 120mm fans on them to keep the memory from overheating. But I got them for 25% off, so I guess that's the trade off :) Depending on your manufacturer, generally they will start throttling at about 85 to 90. I know when Tom's Hardware was benchmarking the 4870's, they ran into the same throttling issue.